# Cesaro means $\frac{1}{N} \sum_1^{N} a_n$ of a positive sequence converging to zero while the sequence itself does not

Tags: sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

In this post: [Cesaro means of a positive sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901952/cesaro-means-of-a-positive-sequence), OP is referring to a "famous example" of a sequence $a_n \geq 0$ whose Cesaro means $\frac{1}{N} \sum_1^{N} a_n$ converge to zero while the sequence itself does not. What "famous example" is OP referring to?

Comment: Indeed, thank you Martin. I expected an answer to be found and have searched the forum extensively but the post did not appear.

Comment: Well, I just typed “Cesaro example” into the search field of this site and got that as a top hit ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take
$$a_k = 1 \quad \text{ if } k=2^n \text{ for a }n \in \mathbb{N} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad a_k=0 \text{ otherwise}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Doe.